# problem in pagination with requestAction

Tags: cakephp, paging

I am developing a app in cakephp( ver 1.3) , where  i need dynamic
routing. So to do this i call requestAction method in config/
routes.php

$routingData=Object::requestAction(array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'get_routes'));

Router::connect('/pages/blog', array('controller' =>'blogs', 'action'
=>'index'));

It rendering properly but i am facing problem with pagination.

Original(Requested) url is
(http://)localhost/pushpanelnew/pages/blog

Pagination link are like
(http://)localhost/pushpanelnew/pages/get_routes/page:2   for page 2

But i want pagination link like
(http://)localhost/pushpanelnew/pages/blog/page:2

I also try using this

$this->Paginator->options(array('url'=>$this->params['url']['url']));

But it showing  link like

(http://)localhost/pushpanelnew/pages/get_routes/pages/blog/page:2

Also pagination is not working

But i want the pagination link like

(http://)localhost/pushpanelnew/pages/blog/page:2

Please help me , its very urgent.

Thanks

Timir Maji

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$this->Paginator->options(array('url'=> array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'blog'));
```

Comment: i solve it in different way, so i want to put it also .After putting it i will marked as answered